# Keras Binary Classification

Tags: keras

I tune my keras model and got good logloss and accuracy result.

Test loss: 0.205
Test accuracy: 0.938

[image: I have attached here the result]

However, when I predict on my holdout data using predict_proba it is disappointing (very high logloss). Any help please. this is my first keras model.

```
# resample data with SMOTEEN
smoteen = SMOTEENN(random_state=42) # ratio={0:438, 1:400},
X_res, y_res = smoteen.fit_resample(X, y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_transform,y_res,                            
    test_size = 0.30, random_state=42, stratify=y_res)

# Save the number of columns in predictors: n_cols
n_cols = X_train.shape[1]
input_shape = (n_cols,)


# create model
def create_model(input_shape=input_shape, optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001)), 
    kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.RandomUniform()):

model = Sequential()# 
model.add(Dense(500,   
    activation='relu',kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,  
    input_shape=input_shape,))  
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(.5))

model.add(Dense(950,activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape, 
    kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer))       
model.add(BatchNormalization())
kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),
model.add(Dropout(.25))   

model.add(Dense(950,activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape, 
    kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer))  
model.add(BatchNormalization())
kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),
model.add(Dropout(.25))


model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))  
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=optimizer, metrics=
    ['accuracy'] )
return model

model = create_model()
batch_size = 32
epochs = 500

history=model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size= batch_size, 
    epochs=epochs, verbose=2, validation_data=(X_test, y_test),   
    validation_split=0.2,)  

scores=model.evaluate(X_test,y_test)
print('\n%s: %.2f%%' % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))

predictions = model.predict_proba(holdout_1_transform, batch_size=32)
```

Comment: It's not possible to answer your question if you don't provide any information about what and how you're doing. Check for preprocessing, it must be exactly the same in all data groups, for both input and outputs. Also check for accidentally training the test data mixed with the train data.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an overfitting problem. I think it's too broad to answer here but there are usually several things to try in similar situation.

- Get more training data
- Dropout (which you already have)
- Stop the training earlier

If I get it right your test data is about 30% of all data (`test_size = 0.30`). If you have enough data, say hundred(s) of thousand of samples, it should be enough to use just 1% or 2%, or maybe even less.

I also notices you trained for 100 epochs. Judging by the Loss chart, try training for 10 or 20 epochs - the training and validation performance should be slightly worse but it could help with the performance on the holdout data.

Again, these are just assumptions and guesses. The term you are looking for is `overfit`.

Comment: Thanks stan0 for your candid reply.